# 4 Port USB 2.0 Switch

Tags: usb, switches, usb-host, usb-hub

I am currently working on a device that is able to switch four USB devices back and forth between two PCs (see picture). For the task I wanted to use a "TUSB4041" as a USB hub and the "HD3SS6126" as a USB switch between the two PCs. For better understanding I created a block diagram to illustrate my plans.

[image]

However, during my research on USB 2.0 switching, I came across an important fact. When connecting and disconnecting USB 2.0, a certain order must be followed. VDD has to be connected before D+ and D- and disconnected the other way around. I searched the internet for example schematics about USB 2.0 switching and noticed that most schematics either switch all four poles at the same time or only D+/D- back and forth.

So my first question is: Do I have to follow this connection and disconnection sequence for USB 2.0 high-speed or can I ignore it?

When the answer is yes, do you have an idea how I can best implement this switching delay between VDD and D+/D-, during connection and disconnection, in my schematic?

Comment: but you aren't actually switching VDD at all, are you? You have to connect the power before the data, and disconnect the power after the data, so the device always has power if it has data. How is your device not already doing this? Is it switching the power before the data? No, it's not

Comment: "I came across an important fact" - for scientific work (which you're hopefully doing), you want to reference your sources. "can I ignore it?" - You found a source saying so. What are your reasons to doubt it? Did you find other sources saying otherwise? Does your own understanding of the matter tell you something different? If so, what is your understanding / your experience? What does the data sheet and example applications/reference design say? Do they implement a delay? Do other USB hubs implement it? Did you reverse engineer some?

Comment: How is your device powered? How is the switch signal controlled?

Comment: Fur USB 2.0, a USB 2.0 mux like the the TMUXHS221 would be much simpler.

Comment: Isn't it the reason the USB connectors are designed that way? By their design, the power will connect first and the data after.